# Passing js value to php without redirecting and running a js function when a page is unloaded or refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I am trying to calculate how much time a web page is being viewed by a user. But I am facing two problems.

1. Using window.location.href I am able to pass my calculated time to my PHP page and update my DB for that page. But this is also redirecting to me that PHP page which I don't want. I want to go backwards or refresh the page or do anything else but also passing the calculated time in my DB when I unload the current page without redirecting.
2. Click The function showElapsedTime is calculating the value of elapsed time, but the js func is only running when Click button is pressed. I want to run this function whenever I unload the current page or refresh the page

Code:

```
<body onload="startTimer()" >
<button onclick="showElapsedTime()>Click</button>
</body>

    <script>
        var id;
        var start;
        var end;
        function startTimer() {
            start = window.performance.now();
            console.log(start);
        }
        function showElapsedTime() {
            end = window.performance.now();
            console.log(end - start);
            var seconds = (end - start) / 1000;
            window.location.href="timer.php?second=" + seconds.toFixed(2) + "&id=" + id;
        }
    </script>
```

If anyone can give me complete solutions to my issues it will be very much helpful.

Comment: Use AJAX to send to PHP without reloading.

Comment: You can use a handler for `unload` to run code when the page is unloaded.

Comment: Looks like a small homebrew of google analytics.  Why not use a pre-existing analytics tool?

Comment: i don't know how to use ajax. I have tried some examples but still failed. Can you give me a proper ajax solution for my code?

Comment: @Barmar also don't know how to use handler for unload

Comment: `window.addEventListener("unload", function() { ... })`

Comment: @Barmar am i supposed to write the showElapsedTime function inside eventlistener?

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting.